# IE 10 popup window disappear behind main window

Tags: internet-explorer, popupwindow

I have a application wrote for Internet Explorer, right now I have a IE10. 
My problem: when i clicked at hiperlink, popup window isn't show correctly- popup window opening behind main window, but window exist but under the main page- when I click at windows bar the popup look ok.
One way to repair this is a reseting Tabs from Tools/ Internet Explorer but this is not for always and I can't force client to runing this all the time.
In this popup window I don't have much  JS code and i think that is not depend of this.
Anyone had this problem and know sth about this?
Regards
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I found that to show property popup window "on top" I can in JavaScript write method:

```
window.focus();
```

inverse this method is a

```
window.blur();
```

To showing You how it works, Please go [there](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_focus) ofcourse please run it in IE10.
To see a difference please change myWindow.focus(); to myWindow.blur();
In IE10 with blur() window should hide under the others page. 
If You have better solution, please write uder.